# How to get value on Azure ARM uniqueString function in Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to get the value returned by **uniqueString** in Powershell. I am creating the bulk of my environment using ARM templates, but I still need to run **Powershell** for certain things. **Powershell** needs to know the resource name suffixes generated by **uniqueString**. Currently I have these values hard coded.

Also, the value returned by **uniqueString** is excessive and severely limits  resource names, ie *espstorage* is too long to use with **uniqueString**. I am considering replacing **uniqueString** with a CRC32 or .Net String Hash value in my templates -- since I end up hard coding the values anyway in **Powershell**. But from all the examples, **uniqueString** appears to be the "correct" way.

Comment: Use an output variable in your ARM template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with subscriptionId. My resolution is at post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56195642/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-subscriptionid-used-in-task-azure-resource-group-dep](http://See%20post:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56195642/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-subscriptionid-used-in-task-azure-resource-group-dep)